# In what units do the rasters need to be to use dismo::biovars?

Tags: raster, terra, climate, rstudio, dismo

I want to calculate bioclimatic variables from CHELSA monthly data using the biovars function from the dismo package but the help page doesn't mention in what units the precipitation and temperature data needs to be.